# How do I set the time.time() timescale in python?

Tags: python, time

I need to mensure time of code part. I'm using time.time() before and after specific code part.

```
startBayes = time.time()

function()

endBayes = time.time()
timeBayes = endBayes-startBayes
```

But, I checked and sometimes that number is in seconds and other times in minutes. How can I define it?

Comment: It's always in seconds, at least in Python 3. What behavior are you getting that suggests otherwise?

Comment: `time.time()` is always a floating point number representing seconds since the UNIX epoch. It is never minutes. Or are you talking about the amount of time that has passed, so `timeBayes` is greater than 60? Either way, it isn't really clear what you are talking about here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are correct! I mistaken with another results in other language ... sorry! In R, output can be with different scales ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) always returns seconds:

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.

Therefore, your time difference will always be in seconds as well.